# The facebook_app_events package for flutter is duplicating the sample activities in the facebook pixel portal

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-pixel, facebook-events

I'm facing a problem with the only Facebook events package available for flutter, which is duplicating the event samples as shown in the screenshot below, does anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

Only a sample event appears, as is the case with other events in the package
[image]